# Get datetime/timestamp from a website/url in android

Tags: android, sql-server

here is what i'am trying to achieve, either one of the two would be ok

- Get the date and time from a specific url/website like "www.mywebsite.com"
- Get the date and time from my MSSQL Server

either one of the two would be ok, because all i need is to get the same time from the website/server's end, because i'am making an APP Version for the Mobile Website i'am making and i want to show a Clock or Date&Time Reminder in the App

i have no codes working as of now, i tried searching online in search engines and also in stackoverflow but i can't seem to find what i'am looking for, either i'am using the wrong words to search for it or there really isn't any way

the reason why i need the date is because i'am checking when the records inside the database was created and verifying how much time has passed since it was created, it like comparing (CreationDateTime & CurrentDateTime)

i can successfully Display how many hours have passed, i just need the CURRENT PROPER & ACCURATE DATE & TIME of the server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found an alternative answer that works 100% in getting date and time from SERVER instead of URL

SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateAndTime

[GETDATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_getdate.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), or at least close to it.

Your client device knows what time it is, because it stays in sync via NTP and whatever network it's attached to (and we already know you're attached to a network because otherwise, this whole thing falls apart). And it knows (or should know) what timezone it's in, so you can translate that to UTC or whatever alternative timezone you might need.

Your server(s) should *also* be keeping time synced via NTP, so drift between the client and server should be sub-second at worst.

IOW, the time (when corrected to UTC, which all date/time libraries I've used have a method built in to do) will almost always match between your client and server, so why bother with the complexity of "pushing" the current time from server to client?

I'm not seeing why you'd need to do this at all. Have the server tell the client when the reminder is set for, then let the client work out the rest. Anything else would be excessively chatty over the network.

Comment: very interesting, so would you approve if i just get the general Internet Time + use the same timezone that the server is using? would that be good enough?

Comment: the reason why i need the date is because i'am checking when the records inside the database was created and verifying how much time has passed since it was created, it like comparing (CreationDateTime & CurrentDateTime)

Comment: if that is the method to use, can you show me how to get the date and time from an internet server? i think i can work from there

Comment: the problem is, i need to make sure that the Client Device's Time and Date doesnt bypass or mess up the system for the App, since the function that iam doing needs to be synced with the time and date of the server, i need to make sure that the USER does not just change the time in the phone and say,,, "look 24hrs have passed" i can do it again

Comment: Again, there is no need to be passing the current time between devices (doubly so since you can't trust the client. Ever. Even when you think you can). Your database server knows the current time, and it knows your "creation" time. Do the date math in the database query itself (`datediff()` is your friend) and pass the result to the client. If control like this is important in a client-server application, you have to do **all** of this logic on the server, because you cannot trust or control the client. At most, ask the client what timezone it's in and then do everything on the server.

Comment: the reason why i need to display it, is because the USER should have a COUNTDOWN on how many more hours left, i can do the countdown, i just want to make sure that the basis for current date and time is correct :)

Comment: i just need to get the time that the server runs on, i autimatically add the date and time of the server when creating records, i just need to know if i can access the date and time of the server,

Comment: Once again, the date and time of the server is **the same** as the date & time of the client if you normalize everything to UTC. So there should be no need to pass it between them in the first place. Server tells the client when the event is to happen (in UTC), then the *client* can do the calculations between "now" (again, in UTC, from the on-device time) and the event time to produce the countdown.

Comment: what if the client has "CHANGED" the date and time of their smartphone? wouldn't that mess it up? i'm just trying to clear out any flaws....

Comment: because i tried to change the date and time of the Test Device, and it was able to bypass "COOLDOWNS" for example, you shouldnt be able to claim FREE STUFF in the game if you did not wait 24hrs, i tried fast forwarding the date by 1 day and it suddenly bypassed the system :(

Comment: here is the situation, I CAN get the records created within less than 24hrs, and i compare it with the current date, to see how many hours are left, now, i just need a reliable source for the current date

if you think you have an answer, please post it, i would really appreciate it ;) i never downvote, because i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

To get the date in the format below, just convert todays date to a string

--07/06/2017

SELECT convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103)

Comment: brother, i know how to change the format, i just need to know how to GET the date :)